# A secure connection cannot be established because this site uses an unsupported protocol

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

I'm not able to make my http requests to https requests. My server domain name is myservers.com. My seniors (left the office) brought wildcard ssl certificate from **comodo RSA Domain Validation secure server CA**. It is working fine when I use https://myservers.com, its showing a default page. Now my MD installed tomcat on the server and said to me make it https. So I uploaded my war file to webapps and its working fine http://myservers.com:8080/. But its not working fine when https://myservers.com:8443/ it showing **This webpage is not available** ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH.
All certificates are available in the location etc/nginx/ssl.

This is my server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443" /> 

    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
               keystoreFile="/etc/nginx/ssl/domain.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"/>
```

In my search I found these two files
1) myservers.com - in the location - etc/nginx/sites-available
2) myservers.com - in the location - etc/nginx/sites-enabled

Both files contains same code

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        listen 443 ssl;

    root /var/www/myservers.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name myappdemo.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/myservers.com.key;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Please help in order to find out the problem

Answer (score 2):

Simply add this 3 lines after "ssl_certificate_key" to solve the problem:

```
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!ADH:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!EXP:!kEDH;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

Good luck!